# how to efficiently use a time series database to plot Barcharts or LinePlots

Tags: dataset, charts, code-request

I have the following input:

```
ClearAll[rawdata1, datas1, rawdata2, datas2, rawdata3, datas3, rawdata4, datas4, chl, mean];

(* import data from four Excel worksheets *)

(*
rawdata1=Import["C:\\Users\\ttemel\\Downloads\\LDC_data.xlsx",{"Data", 13}];
rawdata2=Import["C:\\Users\\ttemel\\Downloads\\LDC_data.xlsx",{"Data", 14}];
rawdata3=Import["C:\\Users\\ttemel\\Downloads\\LDC_data.xlsx",{"Data", 15}];
rawdata4=Import["C:\\Users\\ttemel\\Downloads\\LDC_data.xlsx",{"Data", 16}];
*)
```

For easiness of illustration, here are the 4 datasets imported from four Excel worksheets:

```
rawdata1 = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", "x3"},
    {"t1", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 1.`, 2.`, 3.`}, {"t1", "c2", "R1", "SR2", 4.`, 2.`, 8.`},
    {"t1", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 5.`, 7.`, 6.`}, {"t1", "c4", "R2", "SR2", 4.`, 8.`, 1.`}};
rawdata2 = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t2", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 0.`, 2.`, 4.`}, {"t2", "c2", 
    "R1", "SR2", 1.`, 2.`, 1.`}, {"t2", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 3.`, 5.`, 
    8.`}, {"t2", "c4", "R2", "SR2", 4.`, 8.`, 3.`}};
rawdata3 = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t3", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 3.`, 2.`, 5.`}, {"t3", "c2", 
    "R1", "SR2", 1.`, 3.`, 2.`}, {"t3", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 2.`, 5.`, 
    1.`}, {"t3", "c4", "R2", "SR2", 7.`, 3.`, 8.`}};
rawdata4 = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t4", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 6.`, 3.`, 1.`}, {"t4", "c2", 
    "R1", "SR2", 2.`, 2.`, 5.`}, {"t4", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 6.`, 8.`, 
    1.`}, {"t4", "c4", "R2", "SR2", 1.`, 2.`, 9.`}};
```

Then, I created individual databases, one for each period (because sometimes I use only one database for the analysis):

```
datas1 = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@rawdata1 -> #] & /@ Rest@rawdata1];
datas2 = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@rawdata2 -> #] & /@ Rest@rawdata2];
datas3 = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@rawdata3 -> #] & /@ Rest@rawdata3];
datas4 = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@rawdata4 -> #] & /@ Rest@rawdata4];
```

See the output format of the four databases:

```
{TableForm[datas1], TableForm[datas2], TableForm[datas3], TableForm[datas4]}
```

Since I have `time`, `country`, `region` and `subregion` indices, combining individual databases as a single database gives me flexibility in programming:

```
jdata = Join[datas1, datas2, datas3, datas4];
```

from which I want to retrieve data to plot various charts such as `BarCharts` and `LinePlots`. Here is an example for retrieving data for `x3` across countries and time:

```
(* needs improvement in selection method *)
tsC1x3 = jdata[{1, 5, 9, 13}][[All, "x3"]];  (* retrieve time series data for a single country 1 and a single variable x3 *)
tsC2x3 = jdata[{2, 6, 10, 14}][[All, "x3"]]; (* retrieve time series data for a single country 2 and a single variable x3 *)
tsC3x3 = jdata[{3, 7, 11, 15}][[All, "x3"]];
tsC4x3 = jdata[{4, 8, 12, 16}][[All, "x3"]];
```

Now, I draw `Barchart`

```
ClearAll[chl];
chl = {"Bhutan", "Cambodia", "Tonga", "Lao PDR"};
BarChart[
 Join[tsC1x3, tsC2x3, tsC3x3, tsC4x3],
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12],
 ChartLayout -> "Grouped",
 ChartLegends -> Placed[{"t=1", "t=2", "t=3", "t=4"}, Below],
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[chl, {{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &],
    None},
 ChartStyle -> {
   RGBColor[{157, 135, 122}/255 // N],
   RGBColor[{251, 195, 011}/255 // N],
   RGBColor[{198, 030, 044}/255 // N],
   RGBColor[{027, 150, 212}/255 // N]
   },
 PlotTheme -> "Business",
 PlotLabel -> Style["X3 across countries and time", Black, Bold, 12],
 BarOrigin -> Bottom,
 BarSpacing -> {0.1, 4},
 FrameLabel -> {None, Row[{Spacer[1], Style["USD", Bold, 11]}]},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Background -> Lighter[Gray, .9],
 AspectRatio -> 1/2
 ]
```

My problems start here.

1. The `Barchart` produced using the above `code` does not group four countries across four years. You will see it when you plot the bar chart.
2. Country labels for each time series group are not shown.
3. Last but most difficult is to make the selection of cross-section (for a given time) and time-series (for a given variable) as is seen from the definitions `tsC1x3, tsC2x3, tsC3x3, tsC4x3`. What I want to achieve is simple. For example, I want to draw a single `Barchart` for all countries across all years for a given variable. OR I want to draw a time-series trend of a variable over time for a single country and so on.
4. I am looking for an effective way to select desired data using the 4 indices (time, country, region, and subregion). Currently, it is not efficient nor doable for very large datasets. A systematic method for the extraction of data is most welcome.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A better way to select country/variable `tsC1x3 = jdata[Select[#country == "c1" &], "x3"]`

Comment: @Rohit: For one country, `BarChart[jdata[Select[#country == "c1" &], "x3"]]` works fine. For all the countries `jdata[GroupBy["country"], BarChart[ #]&, "x3"]` works fine. If I change grouping to `GroupBy["time"]` I do the same across time. My biggest problem is to combine individual country bar charts as a single bar chart. Imagine a bar chart showing each country bar chart on the same plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

To simplify your code **use indexed variables**

```
rawdata[1] = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t1", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 1.`, 2.`, 3.`}, {"t1", "c2", "R1", "SR2",
     4.`, 2.`, 8.`}, {"t1", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 5.`, 7.`, 6.`}, {"t1", "c4", 
    "R2", "SR2", 4.`, 8.`, 1.`}};
rawdata[2] = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t2", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 0.`, 2.`, 4.`}, {"t2", "c2", "R1", "SR2",
     1.`, 2.`, 1.`}, {"t2", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 3.`, 5.`, 8.`}, {"t2", "c4", 
    "R2", "SR2", 4.`, 8.`, 3.`}};
rawdata[3] = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t3", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 3.`, 2.`, 5.`}, {"t3", "c2", "R1", "SR2",
     1.`, 3.`, 2.`}, {"t3", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 2.`, 5.`, 1.`}, {"t3", "c4", 
    "R2", "SR2", 7.`, 3.`, 8.`}};
rawdata[4] = {{"time", "country", "region", "subregion", "x1", "x2", 
    "x3"}, {"t4", "c1", "R1", "SR1", 6.`, 3.`, 1.`}, {"t4", "c2", "R1", "SR2",
     2.`, 2.`, 5.`}, {"t4", "c3", "R2", "SR1", 6.`, 8.`, 1.`}, {"t4", "c4", 
    "R2", "SR2", 1.`, 2.`, 9.`}};

datas[n_Integer?Positive] := 
  Dataset[AssociationThread[First@rawdata[n] -> #] & /@ Rest@rawdata[n]];

jdata = Join @@ (datas /@ Range[4]);

ts[ctry_, var_] := jdata[Select[#country == ctry &], var]

cs[t_, var_] := jdata[Select[#time == t &], var]

countries = {"Bhutan", "Cambodia", "Tonga", "Lao PDR"};
```

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to control the data display

```
Manipulate[
 BarChart[
  If[group === "Country",
   Normal[ts[#, var]] & /@ {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"},
   Normal[cs[#, var]] & /@ {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"}], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12], 
  ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[If[group === "Country",
     {"t=1", "t=2", "t=3", "t=4"}, countries], Below],
  ChartLabels -> {If[group === "Country", countries,
     {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"}], None}, 
  ChartStyle -> {
    RGBColor[{157, 135, 122}/255 // N], 
    RGBColor[{251, 195, 011}/255 // N], 
    RGBColor[{198, 030, 044}/255 // N], 
    RGBColor[{027, 150, 212}/255 // N]}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  PlotLabel -> 
    Style[var <> " across countries and time", Black, Bold, 12], 
  BarOrigin -> Bottom, 
  BarSpacing -> {0.1, 4}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, Row[{Spacer[1], Style["USD", Bold, 11]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, .9], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2],
 Row[{
   Control[{{group, "Country"}, {"Country", "Time"}}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[{{var, "x3"}, {"x1", "x2", "x3"}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really great. I was imagining this answer but was afraid of asking it. You read my mind. I really appreciate your effort and code.

Answer (score 3):

```
jdata = Join @@ Map[a |->
 Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ a, #] & /@ Rest[a]]][
  {rawdata1, rawdata2, rawdata3, rawdata4}];

groupeddata = jdata[GroupBy[#country &], GroupBy[#time &], All, {"x1", "x2", "x3"}];

Row[{jdata, groupeddata}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Define a [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) that constructs a `BarChart` from selected columns of `groupeddata`:

```
ClearAll[barChart, bcQ]

barChart[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := BarChart[#, opts,
    ChartLabels -> Automatic, ChartLegends -> Automatic] &;

bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var_String, countryslices_: All, 
  timeslices_: All, f_: Identity] := Query[
   (countryslices /. {All -> Identity, x_List :> KeyTake[x]}) /* 
     (barChart[opts, PlotLabel -> var][f[#]] &), 
   timeslices /. x_List :> KeyTake[x], 
   First@*First@*Values@* KeyTake[var]]

bcQ[opts : OptionsPattern[]][var_List, rest___] := 
 Row[Append[#[[All, 1]], #[[1, -1, 1, 1]]] & @
    Through[(bcQ[opts][#, rest] & /@ var) @ #], Spacer[10]] &
```

**Examples:**

```
bcQ[ImageSize -> 400, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> ({Mean @ #[[1]], Max @ #[[2]]} &), 
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"][{"x1"}] @ groupeddata
```

[image]

Take countries `"c1"`, `"c2"` and `"c4"` and group by time and then by country:

```
bcQ[ImageSize -> 400, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> ({Mean @ #[[1]], Max @ #[[2]]} &), 
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"][{"x3"},  {"c1", "c2", "c4"}, All, Transpose]@groupeddata
```

[image]

Take multiple measures (say, `"x1"` and `"x3"`) for countries `{"c1", "c2", "c4"}`:

```
bcQ[ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
   Joined -> ({Mean @ #[[1]], Max @ #[[2]]} &), 
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"][{"x1", "x3"},  {"c1", "c2", "c4"}]@groupeddata
```

[image]

Interactively select measures, times and countries using `Manipulate`:

```
tlist = Normal @ Keys @ Transpose @ groupeddata;
clist = Normal @ Keys @ groupeddata
xlist = First @ Normal @ Keys @ groupeddata[1, 1];

Manipulate[
 bcQ[ImageSize -> 400, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Joined -> ({Mean@#[[1]], Max@#[[2]]} &), 
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"][Sort@vars, countries, times, gorder]@groupeddata,
 {{vars, xlist[[{1}]], "measures"}, xlist, TogglerBar},
 {{countries, clist, "countries"}, clist, TogglerBar},
 {{times, tlist, "times"}, tlist, TogglerBar},
 {{gorder, Identity, "grouping order"}, 
     {Identity -> Column[{ "country", "time"}, Alignment -> Center], 
      Transpose -> Column[{"time", "country"}, Alignment -> Center]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really, the level of flexibility in producing different charts is amazing. I need a few days to digest your high-level code. I was busy preparing a different dataset with both irregular `time` and irregular `variables` to produce similar charts. I will post a new question today.

Comment: Somehow, I have a problem with `jdata = Join @@ Map[a |-> ...` where `a|->` seems to be the problem. Maybe there is a typo in that line.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, try using `\[Function]` in place of `|->`.

Comment: Maybe you can correct another typo in your code above, which is a missing comma `(,)` after `rawdata1` in the `jdata = Join @@ Map[a |-> Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ a, #] & /@ Rest[a]]][{rawdata1 rawdata2, rawdata3, rawdata4}];` Then the code will work nicely

Comment: I added the missing comma. The form  `|->` is  added in version 12.2 ([see Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html?q=Function))