# how to use an unformatted database imported from Excel into Mathematica and draw various charts

Tags: dataset, charts, code-request, data-acquisition

In my earlier question ([in this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257342/60365))
the given database is nicely formatted with columns denoting data for variables across countries and years.

But, data sets are not always nicely formatted. Here is an unformatted database (I created for minimal exposition to formulate my question) in which all the data are presented in a single column, as well as variable names repeated in another single column. Time periods across variables and countries are not identical. For one country, the available data may extend from 2001 to 2020 but for another country, the same variable may be short-lived from 2005 to 2015. Furthermore, countries are grouped into two categories: LDC and ODC. Given all these limitations, I like to generate `BarCharts` and `ListLinePlot` as illustrated in the above link. I know that `Manipulate` is so powerful if it is used efficiently, and that I would like to have the charts in `Manipulate` as it allows for very easy scenarios of the parameters.

In the current database given below, there are four parameters: `{country, status, vars, time}` that will be used depending on the type of chart to be produced.

**Example:** Draw a single `BarChart` with all the countries and all years for a single (multiple) variable `vars` across country status (LDC and ODC). This is just an example of many others.

```
rawdata1 = {{"country", "status", "vars", "time", "data"}, {"Bhutan", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2012.`, 11.7317902498375`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2013.`, 7.89168738800201`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2014.`, 5.07109529390251`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2015.`, 2.14228177446305`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2016.`, 3.99347434438733`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2017.`, 6.64235386538354`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2018.`, 8.1271556376086`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2019.`, 4.65170017994314`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2020.`, 3.02767016810783`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2021.`, 3.80610777007113`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2009.`, 0.740265356463854`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2010.`, 0.740265356463854`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2011.`, 0.740265356463854`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2012.`, 0.740265356463854`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2013.`, 2.01311158452329`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2014.`, 2.01311158452329`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2015.`, 2.14228177446305`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2016.`, 2.14228177446305`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2017.`, 2.14228177446305`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2018.`, 2.14228177446305`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2008.`, 82.7500899512726`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2009.`, 69.5307200123119`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2010.`, 58.0567671342573`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2011.`, 66.462854452616`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2012.`, 64.0152496294596`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2013.`, 64.3635506717257`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2014.`, 88.4379637469247`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2015.`, 93.5919296023436`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2018.`, 116.021645859231`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2019.`, 116.55424756929`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2020.`, 114.619068673739`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2007.`, 2.79220345990346`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2008.`, 4.84585842175085`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2009.`, 11.8507099824423`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2010.`, 12.6844892415372`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2016.`, 17.2355189434556`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2017.`, 16.5847794392432`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2018.`, 11.0524403566625`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2019.`, 10.718740205243`}, {"Bhutan", "LDC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2020.`, 7.51326635700829`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC",
    "GDP growth", 2013.`, 6.4643849452773`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2014.`, 6.52145155902684`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2015.`, 6.01361059194194`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2016.`, 6.06107852277686`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2017.`, 6.55263331602802`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2018.`, 7.1134894741232`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2019.`, 7.28418409195113`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2020.`, 7.86371944223927`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2021.`, 8.15268414939789`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2011.`, 3.39981548740751`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2012.`, 3.39981548740751`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2013.`, 4.08468894261222`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2014.`, 4.08468894261222`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2015.`, 4.08468894261222`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2016.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2017.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2018.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2019.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2020.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2021.`, 4.41555612209166`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2006.`, 29.0231053050116`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2007.`, 25.5142249883711`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2012.`, 21.3186585394465`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2013.`, 19.4789273407571`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2014.`, 19.5470222088404`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2015.`, 19.439616467771`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2016.`, 17.7117967565762`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2017.`, 17.3096636682518`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2018.`, 16.430183438899`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2019.`, 17.9742504913686`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2020.`, 18.1937153154054`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "External debt", 2021.`, 18.0142002753455`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2009.`, 5.31781131096202`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC",
    "Debt servicing", 2010.`, 6.0412536184725`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC",
    "Debt servicing", 2011.`, 5.08243215255821`}, {"Bangladesh", 
   "ODC", "Debt servicing", 2012.`, 5.62926552857404`}, {"Bangladesh",
    "ODC", "Debt servicing", 2013.`, 
   5.84313717722571`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", "Debt servicing", 2014.`,
    5.92461780359757`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", "Debt servicing", 
   2015.`, 5.87634917084482`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", "Debt servicing",
    2016.`, 4.65398848053981`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC", 
   "Debt servicing", 2017.`, 4.63526201562755`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC",
    "Debt servicing", 2018.`, 5.4542264908716`}, {"Bangladesh", "ODC",
    "Debt servicing", 2019.`, 6.44420242273907`}, {"Bangladesh", 
   "ODC", "Debt servicing", 2020.`, 12.8165870165076`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2008.`, -0.0493465149077776`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2009.`, 2.03503444919169`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2010.`, -2.09164562868308`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2011.`, 0.802961941412161`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2012.`, -0.924067932533501`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2016.`, -0.604818488715408`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2017.`, 10.2959730488488`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2018.`, 1.14025038951184`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2019.`, 4.88310317936931`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2020.`, 2.31308712014162`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP growth", 2021.`, 2.29661272883723`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2002.`, -9.80119924951005`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2011.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2012.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2013.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2014.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2015.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2016.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2017.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2018.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2019.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2020.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Kiribati", 
   "LDC", "GDP shocks", 2021.`, -4.7598081474706`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2006.`, 4.68260324535137`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2007.`, 3.47918104631144`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2008.`, 3.36461478807166`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2009.`, 3.41156027569265`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2010.`, 6.10463914231689`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2011.`, 4.53307872039284`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2015.`, 4.12887767631092`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2016.`, 5.98893336810162`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2017.`, 3.32295600970052`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2018.`, 0.588654958809332`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2019.`, 8.2234809809647`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2020.`, 6.70103808547462`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP growth", 2021.`, 6.99121243750931`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2002.`, -2.9780114727446`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2011.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2012.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2013.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2014.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2015.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2016.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2017.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2018.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2019.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2020.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2021.`, 0.119813643353961`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2009.`, 34.6388304814776`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2010.`, 29.1821447836312`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2013.`, 20.1190041573439`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2014.`, 20.0489422598981`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2015.`, 20.6639601633151`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2016.`, 19.5755300670239`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2017.`, 19.0433862315843`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2018.`, 19.9827561972183`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2019.`, 19.4856042520084`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2020.`, 18.7510220424003`}, {"Nepal", "LDC", 
   "External debt", 2021.`, 21.0138276442613`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2005.`, -3.10512510825693`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2006.`, -1.67649286925071`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2007.`, -4.11822919782043`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2008.`, 2.89081209141946`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2009.`, 6.34681136452036`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2010.`, 7.0953263780791`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2014.`, -3.88415250965769`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2015.`, 4.91003579781166`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2016.`, 1.17773912883179`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2017.`, 9.23046021376099`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2018.`, 5.88457557563717`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2019.`, 5.9374411336264`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2020.`, 7.00612804279335`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP growth", 2021.`, 6.27479376033349`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2002.`, -16.0091403253025`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2003.`, -16.0091403253025`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2004.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2005.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2009.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2010.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2015.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2016.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2017.`, -5.96132941753422`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2018.`, -4.13246880255104`}, {"Tuvalu", "ODC", 
   "GDP shocks", 2019.`, -4.13246880255104`}};
```

You can see the above database in a table format:

```
jdata = Join@@Map[a \[Function] 
      Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ Rest[a]]][{rawdata1}]
```

Comment: As formulated, yours is a request for work-for-hire, rather than a request for help. Any approach would necessarily have to be tailored to the structure of your data set, and therefore be of little general use to future readers. Instead, could you include what you have tried so far, and identify the specific step that gave you trouble?

Comment: @MarcoB :  I tried various things to basically put the unformatted dataset into a formatted structure shown in the `Link`, which is the easiest way to get around my question/request. My trials not worth giving them here include various `Matrix Operations` on `jdata` using  `If` and `AppendTo` statements. My purpose was to build a new matrix  (i.e.,  a formatted dataset) of the selected elements. Once I construct it, then the rest of the answer is already given by @Bob Hanlon and@kglr.   Any guidance or code to accomplish this transformation is sufficient for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jdatagrouped = jdata[GroupBy[{#country &, #vars &}] /* KeySort,
   All, All, {DateObject[{Round@#time}], #data} &]
```

[image]

```
jdatagrouped["Bhutan", DateListPlot]
```

[image]

```
jdatagrouped[Map[DateListPlot]]["Bhutan"]
```

> same picture

```
DateListPlot @ jdatagrouped["Bhutan"]
```

> same picture

```
jdatagrouped[DateListPlot, "GDP growth"]
```

[image]

```
jdatagrouped[Map[DateListPlot], {"GDP growth", "GDP shocks"}]["Bangladesh"]
```

[image]

Comment: Using a different data set of the exact same structure above, the command `jdatagrouped[Map[DateListPlot], {"Tax revenues"}]["Bhutan"]` gives me the following error message: `Failure[DateListPlot, 
Association["MessageTemplate" :> MessageName[DateListPlot, "dtvals"], 
   "MessageParameters" -> {}]]["Bhutan"]`. Furthermore, I re-wrote your code as `jdatagrouped = jdata[GroupBy[{#country &, #status &, #vars &}] /* KeySort, All, All, {DateObject[{Round@#time}], #data} &];` Adding  `#status &`  produces an error. Any idea why?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, not sure about the cause of  first issue. The second issue can be fixed using `{{#country , #status }&, #vars &}` instead of `{#country &, #status &, #vars &}`.

Comment: It seems that normal commands for drawing are not suitable if I add `#status`. I tried to make a `ListLinePlot` of only those countries with `LDC` group or make a simple average of `GDP growth` only for the `LDC` group. Basically, my question is `what is the order of selection of the parameters?`

Comment: " `DateListPlot[jdatagrouped["Bhutan", {"GDP growth", "GDP shocks"}], 
 Filling -> Bottom]` is working.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, try using `groupedjd = 
 jdata[GroupBy[{#status &, #country &, #vars &}], All, All, 
  All, {DateObject[{Round@#time}], #data} &]` . Then you can use `DateListPlot@groupedjd["LDC", {"Bhutan", "Nepal"}, "GDP growth"]` , `DateListPlot /@ groupedjd["LDC", All, {"GDP growth", "GDP shocks"}]` etc.