# how to make BarCharts or Line Plot based on specific identifiers in a Dataset over two years

Tags: plotting, dataset, charts, code-request

Given the following datasets:

```
rawdataNew1 = {{"time", "subregion", "country", "status", 
"consumption", "exports", "government exp", "real GDP", "cpi", 
"production index"}, {2020.`, "South Asia", "Afghanistan", "LDC", 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 28.8`, 27.048600499362`}, {2020.`, 
"South Asia", "Bangladesh", "LDC", 79.2`, 75.2`, 16.`, 15.`, 
9.816957121888048`, 9.556161122013`}, {2020.`, "South Asia", 
"Bhutan", "LDC", 65.8`, 78.4`, 43.`, 34.`, 28.1063370463385`, 
29.498494702024`}, {2020.`, "South Asia", "India", "ODC", 65.7`, 
72.3`, 22.`, 18.`, 19.828018499703`, 18.727411344017`}, {2020.`, 
"South Asia", "Maldives", "ODC", 5.`, 61.4`, 25.`, 69.`, 
25.676828054044`, 26.39690268758`}, {2020.`, "South Asia", "Nepal",
"LDC", 88.5`, 81.`, 10.`, 9.`, 22.25877653822`, 
21.923054833825`}, {2020.`, "South Asia", "Pakistan", "ODC", 90.`, 
94.6`, 14.`, 10.`, 14.101228347339`, 15.113000954329`}, {2020.`, 
"South Asia", "Sri Lanka", "ODC", 76.9`, 78.7`, 20.`, 23.`, 
13.085048793291001`, 9.622172267201`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Brunei Darussalam", "ODC", 36.9`, 45.5`, 67.`, 58.`, 
25.690233099619`, 8.8065584881334`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Cambodia", "LDC", 87.6`, 74.2`, 54.`, 61.`, 25.4990651142935`, 
22.473359175818`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", "Indonesia", "ODC", 
65.2`, 66.7`, 24.`, 18.`, 14.5172000188245`, 
12.364844516393`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", "Laos", "LDC", 86.5`,
 25.`, 35.`, 25.`, 15.8137596099375`, 12.054639364958`}, {2020.`, 
"Southeast Asia", "Malaysia", "ODC", 60.7`, 71.5`, 87.`, 65.`, 
20.7378499035525`, 20.357776189578`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Myanmar (Burma)", "LDC", 67.3`, 70.4`, 20.`, 30.`, 
16.989257478684`, 16.037629612146`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Philippines", "ODC", 79.9`, 85.7`, 33.`, 28.`, 19.6007801467695`, 
19.647786797883`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", "Singapore", "ODC", 
46.`, 46.2`, 198.`, 174.`, 17.801460780012498`, 
17.691486935944`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", "Thailand", "ODC", 
68.`, 66.2`, 66.`, 60.`, 21.209241317252`, 
20.604531723764`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Timor-Leste (East Timor)", "LDC", 174.6`, 101.8`, 9.`, 28.`, 
51.011741055190996`, 50.817786342346`}, {2020.`, "Southeast Asia", 
"Vietnam", "ODC", 72.6`, 74.6`, 72.`, 107.`, 19.515540437329`, 
16.171258043431`}, {2020.`, "Eastern Asia", "China", "ODC", 25.`, 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 28.024850206732502`, 25.592166507773`}, {2020.`, 
"Eastern Asia", "Japan", "ODC", 77.2`, 75.4`, 15.`, 19.`, 
34.202910551386495`, 34.050113431921`}, {2020.`, "Eastern Asia", 
"Mongolia", "ODC", 67.9`, 66.8`, 47.`, 60.`, 31.806646933783497`, 
28.155524418943`}, {2020.`, "Eastern Asia", "North Korea", "ODC", 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`}, {2020.`, "Eastern Asia", 
"South Korea", "ODC", 64.6`, 65.7`, 47.`, 40.`, 22.9669437944995`, 
22.826303441138`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "American Samoa", "LDC", 25.`, 
25.`, 63.`, 69.`, 25.`, 25.`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Fiji", "ODC", 
87.3`, 80.2`, 57.`, 48.`, 26.207533616694498`, 
20.495646073594`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "French Polynesia", "ODC", 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Guam", 
"ODC", 25.`, 25.`, 17.`, 20.`, 25.`, 25.`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", 
"Hong Kong SAR, China", "ODC", 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 
20.479931410596002`, 19.675156944555`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", 
"Kiribati", "LDC", 151.3`, 150.7`, 12.`, 10.`, 127.60830739469`, 
104.92502571463`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Marshall Islands", "ODC", 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 62.258733961046005`, 
66.472089105629`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Micronesia", "ODC", 25.`, 
25.`, 24.`, 35.`, 77.6519950815505`, 66.200820487362`}, {2020.`, 
"SIDS", "Nauru", "ODC", 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 
137.10787328369003`, 166.03066370088`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", 
"New Caledonia", "ODC", 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 
25.`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Northern Maria Islands", "ODC", 25.`, 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Palau", "ODC", 
106.2`, 103.6`, 49.`, 48.`, 43.937590802136`, 
42.766858440495`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Papua New Guinea", "ODC", 
25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 25.`, 17.002268918370497`, 
13.917009141834`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Samoa", "ODC", 25.`, 25.`, 
28.`, 37.`, 33.8866916421535`, 38.486285723977`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", 
"Solomon Islands", "LDC", 25.`, 25.`, 40.`, 25.`, 
36.5675228455985`, 31.353772203441`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Tonga", 
"ODC", 116.9`, 25.`, 13.`, 21.`, 42.1411902303165`, 
45.121161008633`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", "Tuvalu", "LDC", 25.`, 25.`, 
25.`, 25.`, 145.083027264305`, 131.81684280884`}, {2020.`, "SIDS", 
"Vanuatu", "LDC", 79.5`, 25.`, 47.`, 25.`, 41.1807536476675`, 
44.808455359488`}, {2020.`, "Pacific", "Australia", "ODC", 74.2`, 
74.3`, 20.`, 24.`, 35.0470091855735`, 35.032340730559`}, {2020.`, 
"Pacific", "New Zealand", "ODC", 77.6`, 75.9`, 30.`, 28.`, 
36.928656157283`, 36.724972823768`}}

rawdataNew2 = {{"time", "subregion", "country", "status", 
   "consumption", "exports", "government exp", "real GDP", "cpi", 
   "production index"}, {2019.`, "South Asia", "Afghanistan", "LDC", 
   10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 27.048600499362`}, {2019.`, 
   "South Asia", "Bangladesh", "LDC", 79.2`, 75.2`, 16.`, 15.`, 
   9.816957121888048`, 9.556161122013`}, {2019.`, "South Asia", 
   "Bhutan", "LDC", 65.8`, 78.4`, 43.`, 34.`, 28.1063370463385`, 
   29.498494702024`}, {2019.`, "South Asia", "India", "ODC", 65.7`, 
   72.3`, 22.`, 18.`, 19.828018499703`, 18.727411344017`}, {2019.`, 
   "South Asia", "Maldives", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 69.`, 
   25.676828054044`, 26.39690268758`}, {2019.`, "South Asia", "Nepal",
    "LDC", 88.5`, 81.`, 10.`, 9.`, 22.25877653822`, 
   21.923054833825`}, {2019.`, "South Asia", "Pakistan", "ODC", 90.`, 
   94.6`, 14.`, 10.`, 14.101228347339`, 15.113000954329`}, {2019.`, 
   "South Asia", "Sri Lanka", "ODC", 76.9`, 78.7`, 20.`, 23.`, 
   13.085048793291001`, 9.622172267201`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Brunei Darussalam", "ODC", 36.9`, 45.5`, 67.`, 58.`, 
   25.690233099619`, 8.8065584881334`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Cambodia", "LDC", 87.6`, 74.2`, 54.`, 61.`, 25.4990651142935`, 
   22.473359175818`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", "Indonesia", "ODC", 
   65.2`, 66.7`, 24.`, 18.`, 14.5172000188245`, 
   12.364844516393`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", "Laos", "LDC", 86.5`,
    10.`, 35.`, 10.`, 15.8137596099375`, 12.054639364958`}, {2019.`, 
   "Southeast Asia", "Malaysia", "ODC", 60.7`, 71.5`, 87.`, 10.`, 
   20.7378499035525`, 20.357776189578`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Myanmar (Burma)", "LDC", 67.3`, 70.4`, 20.`, 10.`, 
   16.989257478684`, 16.037629612146`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Philippines", "ODC", 79.9`, 85.7`, 33.`, 10.`, 19.6007801467695`, 
   19.647786797883`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", "Singapore", "ODC", 
   46.`, 46.2`, 198.`, 10.`, 17.801460780012498`, 
   17.691486935944`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", "Thailand", "ODC", 
   68.`, 66.2`, 66.`, 10.`, 21.209241317252`, 
   20.604531723764`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Timor-Leste (East Timor)", "LDC", 174.6`, 101.8`, 9.`, 10.`, 
   51.011741055190996`, 50.817786342346`}, {2019.`, "Southeast Asia", 
   "Vietnam", "ODC", 72.6`, 74.6`, 72.`, 10.`, 19.515540437329`, 
   16.171258043431`}, {2019.`, "Eastern Asia", "China", "ODC", 10.`, 
   10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 28.024850206732502`, 25.592166507773`}, {2019.`, 
   "Eastern Asia", "Japan", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 15.`, 19.`, 
   34.202910551386495`, 34.050113431921`}, {2019.`, "Eastern Asia", 
   "Mongolia", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 47.`, 60.`, 31.806646933783497`, 
   28.155524418943`}, {2019.`, "Eastern Asia", "North Korea", "ODC", 
   10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`}, {2019.`, "Eastern Asia", 
   "South Korea", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 47.`, 40.`, 22.9669437944995`, 
   22.826303441138`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "American Samoa", "LDC", 10.`, 
   10.`, 63.`, 69.`, 20.`, 20.`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Fiji", "ODC", 
   10.`, 10.`, 57.`, 48.`, 26.207533616694498`, 20.`}, {2019.`, 
   "SIDS", "French Polynesia", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 20.`, 
   20.`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Guam", "ODC", 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 
   20.`, 20.`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Hong Kong SAR, China", "ODC", 10.`, 
   10.`, 10.`, 10.`, 20.479931410596002`, 19.675156944555`}, {2019.`, 
   "SIDS", "Kiribati", "LDC", 151.3`, 150.7`, 10.`, 10.`, 
   127.60830739469`, 104.92502571463`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", 
   "Marshall Islands", "ODC", 20.`, 20.`, 10.`, 10.`, 
   62.258733961046005`, 66.472089105629`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", 
   "Micronesia", "ODC", 20.`, 20.`, 10.`, 10.`, 77.6519950815505`, 
   66.200820487362`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Nauru", "ODC", 20.`, 20.`, 
   10.`, 10.`, 137.10787328369003`, 166.03066370088`}, {2019.`, 
   "SIDS", "New Caledonia", "ODC", 20.`, 20.`, 10.`, 10.`, 20.`, 
   20.`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Northern Maria Islands", "ODC", 20.`, 
   20.`, 10.`, 10.`, 20.`, 20.`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Palau", "ODC", 
   106.2`, 103.6`, 49.`, 48.`, 43.937590802136`, 
   42.766858440495`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Papua New Guinea", "ODC", 
   20.`, 20.`, 20.`, 20.`, 17.002268918370497`, 
   13.917009141834`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Samoa", "ODC", 20.`, 20.`, 
   28.`, 37.`, 33.8866916421535`, 38.486285723977`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", 
   "Solomon Islands", "LDC", 20.`, 20.`, 40.`, 20.`, 
   36.5675228455985`, 31.353772203441`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Tonga", 
   "ODC", 116.9`, 20.`, 13.`, 20.`, 42.1411902303165`, 
   45.121161008633`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", "Tuvalu", "LDC", 20.`, 20.`, 
   20.`, 20.`, 145.083027264305`, 131.81684280884`}, {2019.`, "SIDS", 
   "Vanuatu", "LDC", 79.5`, 20.`, 47.`, 20.`, 41.1807536476675`, 
   44.808455359488`}, {2019.`, "Pacific", "Australia", "ODC", 74.2`, 
   74.3`, 20.`, 24.`, 35.0470091855735`, 35.032340730559`}, {2019.`, 
   "Pacific", "New Zealand", "ODC", 77.6`, 75.9`, 30.`, 28.`, 
   36.928656157283`, 36.724972823768`}}
```

In [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/257342/60365), the answer is already given but with a smaller number of identifiers. In the above datasets, I have 4 identifiers: `{time, subregion, status, country}` across 6 indicators (or variables) across two years. I like to extend the `Manipulate` given in the link to also show `subregion` and `status` so that I can pick a specific subregion and plot those countries in the subregion only. Or I can select a `status` and pick those countries to draw the variables.

The following code produces the combined data set:

```
jdataNew = 
Join @@ Map[a \[Function]
Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ 
    Rest[a]]][{rawdataNew1, rawdataNew2}];

groupeddataNew = 
 jdataNew[GroupBy[#subregion &], GroupBy[#country &], 
  GroupBy[#time &], 
  All, {"consumption", "exports", "government exp", "real GDP", "cpi",
    "production index"}]
```

When I include the identifier `GroupBy[#status &]`, the grouping does not work as seen from  `groupeddataNew`. My purpose is to have a correctly structured data set and use it in `Manipulate` to produce charts and graphs for all the countries in a chosen subregion or in a chosen `status` group, while at the same time having the freedom to choose individual countries at will. The difficulty is that if a `subregion` is chosen, the selection of individual countries is irrelevant as the identifiers should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @WReach: I edited the question with the definition of `jdataNew`. FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) and [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) to filter the data by the identifiers.

With `jdataNew` in the OP the selection lists are created as

```
{statusList, subregionList} = 
    (key |-> Normal[Query[DeleteDuplicates, Slot[key] &]@jdataNew]) /@ {"status", "subregion"}
```

> ```
> {{"LDC", "ODC"}, {"South Asia", "Southeast Asia", "Eastern Asia", "SIDS", "Pacific"}}
> ```

and

```
indicatorList = Normal[Query[First /* Keys]@jdataNew][[5 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {"consumption", "exports", "government exp", "real GDP", "cpi", "production index"}
> ```

Then in [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) construct a `Query` that combines the `Select` from each list with [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) to filter the rows.  [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) is used as before with the addition of swapping the order of the `GroupBy` pair by [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html). Also, the country list is [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)ly updated based on the `status` and `subregion` selection and refreshed on each selection by [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html).

```
Manipulate[
 statusFilter = Switch[status
   , All, True &
   , _, #"status" == status &
   ]
 ; subregionFilter = Switch[subregion
   , All, True &
   , _, #"subregion" == subregion &
   ]
 ; countryFilter = Switch[country
   , All, True &
   , _, #"country" == country &
   ]
 ; data =
  Query[
    Select[statusFilter] /*
     Select[subregionFilter] /*
     Select[countryFilter] /*
     GroupBy[#"country" &]
    , GroupBy[#"time" &]
    , First
    , Evaluate[Slot[indicator]] &
    ]@jdataNew
 ; BarChart[swapGrouing@data
  , ChartLabels -> {(Rotate[#, π/2] & /@ 
      Normal[Keys@swapGrouing@data]), None}
  , ChartLegends -> Automatic
  , ImageSize -> Large
  , PlotLabel -> 
   StringTemplate[
     "``: Region \[Rule] ``, Status \[Rule] ``, Country \[Rule] ``"][
    indicator, subregion, status, country
    ]
  ]
 , {data, None}
 , {statusFilter, None}
 , {{status, All, "Status"}
  , Prepend[All]@statusList
  , ControlType -> SetterBar
  , TrackingFunction -> (country = All; status = #; &)
  }
 , {subregionFilter, None}
 , {{subregion, All, "Subregion"}
  , Prepend[All]@subregionList
  , ControlType -> PopupMenu
  , TrackingFunction -> (country = All; subregion = #; &)
  }
 , {countryFilter, None}
 , {{country, All, "Country"}
  , Dynamic[
   Prepend[All]@
    Normal@Query[
       Select[statusFilter] /*
        Select[subregionFilter] /*
        DeleteDuplicates
       , #"country" &
       ]@jdataNew
   ]
  , ControlType -> PopupMenu
  }
 , {{indicator, First@indicatorList, "Indicator"}, indicatorList, ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 , {{swapGrouing, Identity, "Swap grouping"}, {Identity, Transpose}, ControlType -> Checkbox}
 ]
```

> [image]

I leave the fancy formatting of the chart to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Yes, you can easily modify it by using [`CheckboxBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckboxBar.html) for the `ControlType` and [`MemberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) for the filter.

Comment: @TugrulTemel You must also change the construction of the filters to use `MemberQ`.

Comment: Include your filter using `MemberQ` below.  Let's see where you went wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131070/discussion-between-edmund-and-tugrul-temel).